# scroll bar twitter and facebook timeline widgets

Tags: html, css, facebook, twitter, scroll

I've tried to removed the scroll in the facebook and twitter widgets, but it seems impossible. I got it in the twitter one, but the height changes because what I did is limiting the number of tweets to one.

These are my codes:

for Twitter:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" width="200" height="440"  href="https://twitter.com/enactushope"  data-tweet-limit="1" data-widget-id="347786415695880192"></a>
```

for facebook:

```
<a class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/sheffieldhope/348096328620951" data-width="282" data-chrome="noscrollbar"  data-height="430" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" scrolling="no" data-header="true" style="width:282px; position:absolute; left:-162px;"></a>
```

Comment: try adding `data-chrome="noscrollbar"` to your twitter snippet

Comment: good!! I've tried the same for the facebook one, but it doesn't work! any idea?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page where you have them?

Comment: sure!! http://www.hopesheffield.org/hope

Comment: I guess you fixed this as there's no scrollbars at all on safari

Comment: oh really? but, data-chrome="noscrollbar" doens't work for the Facebook timeline... and what can I do for Internet Explorer? thanks a lot!!

Comment: and also I tried data-chrome="noscrollbar" in the twitter-widget but what happens is that the timeline size changes!! :(